# "side-by-side configuration is incorrect" error when launching Dead Island

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, dead-island

My friend and I both bought the Dead Island game. I set up my copy and it works flawlessly but for my friend it responds with this message "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail". I searched the net exhaustively to find a solution but none of the answers has worked! I would really appreciate any help by you guys!,

We both run 32-bit Windows 7.

Comment: So.. which solutions have you tried? You say that you've tried many, but we can't telepathically know which ones. You need to tell us.

Comment: Yeah sorry for forgetting that... ive tried installing c++ again running in compatibility mode and trying to change the code at the registry but i guess i can try it again if you give me the right link

Answer (score 1):

Looking in Dead Islands manifest I can see a dependency for Microsoft.VC90.CRT.dll version 9.0.21022.8.

Is that located in your Windows\winsxs folder?
If it is check the version number, you probably have the wrong one.

If it's not that, to determine the dll responsible for the side by side error you could download and use this [tool](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). But that gets a bit complicated and would be a better questions for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com),

Answer (score 0):

**Is the game installed via Steam?** If so, the easiest thing to try is to verify the game cache (in other words, force Steam to do a file check on the game files against the repo). If that fails to cause an update, delete something important sounding in the game directory and run it again, as this should (normally) force a re-download. In this case, deleting any '.cfg', '.ini' files or anything that says config, preferences or settings in the game directory would also be useful.